# How to fix the Django-allauth settings.py contrib syntax error?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

So following the current [Django-allauth documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), I keep getting this minor syntax error when I thought I followed the documentation to every last detail.

Terminal error after running: ./manage.py migrate

```
/settings.py", line 43
'django.contrib.auth',
                    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My settings.py file: Was I not supposed to keep the default apps above the allauth section?

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   ...
    # The following apps are required:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    # ... include the providers you want to enable:
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.amazon',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.angellist',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.asana',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **error** is coming because `'django.contrib.auth'` is **repeating**

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
```

and **again**

```
# The following apps are required:
'django.contrib.auth',
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for catching that! Also, I had the ellipsis in there from the online documentation. I just removed those.

Comment: @PandaNinja, If it helped you can vote up and select the answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: I voted it up. The site is telling me to wait a couple of minutes before selecting an answer.

Comment: @PandaNinja, Ohh I was not knowing that. I never asked any question.